# Initializing Array in Class c#

Tags: c#

There is a method to read data from file

```
        public static void ReadData(out StudentMarks[] Students, out int amount)
    {
        amount = 0;
        Students = new StudentMarks[Max];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P3\\P3.2\\StudentsMarks.csv"))
        {
            reader.ReadLine(); reader.ReadLine();
            string line = null;
            int[] marks;
            marks = new int[Max];
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                string surname = values[0];
                string name = values[1];
                string group = values[2];
                int amountOfMarks = int.Parse(values[3]);
                int i = 0; int yMax = 3 + amountOfMarks;int yMin = 4;
                while (amountOfMarks >= i)          
                {
                    if (yMin <= yMax)
                    {
                        marks[i] = int.Parse(values[yMin]);
                        yMin++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            StudentMarks MarksObj = new StudentMarks(surname, name, group, amountOfMarks, marks);
            Students[amount++] = MarksObj;
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a class:

```
class StudentMarks
{
    public const int Max = 50;
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfMarks { get; set; }
    public int[] Marks { get; set; }

    public StudentMarks(string surname, string name, string group, int amountOfMarks, int[] marks)
    {
        Surname = surname;
        Name = name;
        Group = group;
        AmountOfMarks = amountOfMarks;
        Marks = marks;
    }
}
```

The thing is, I cannot read "Marks", because I dont know how to initialize array in Class. My method should be working fine, I just can't put `marks[i]` into `Students[i].Marks[y]`

Comment: Arrays are pretty painful to resize, how about using a `List<int>`. Then just down `marks.Add(int.Parse(yValues[yMin]))`. If you really need it as an array afterwards, you can use Linq and do `marks.ToArray()`

Comment: not sure I understand your problem, but I see something smelling in your Student marks ctor: you require both "amountOfMarks" and the array "marks". In c#, an array always carry its dimension: you can use myArray.Length to know how many elements are in the array. Note the difference with array in C.
Anyway, as @IanofOz suggests, going with a List is the way to go here.

Comment: @IanofOz, ToArray() is a member function of List<T>: no need the help of Linq here!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @GianPaolo - makes it easier still.

Comment: What is the value Max  that is used to defined the `Array`. There's no issue with array initialization challenge is compiler doesn't know what's the value of Max, to do the necessary initialization

Comment: Actually, if you have amountOfMarks, the StudentMarks constructor can just have `Marks = new int[amountOfMarks];` But you work within ReadData would be easier done with List<T> - both List<StudentMarks> and List<int>. The at the last step just do ToArray() on your List<StudentMarks>

Comment: Try one line solution :  int[] marks = values.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want this.

but do you want like it?

```cs
class StudentMarks 
{ 
  public const int Max = 50; 
  public string Surname { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string Group { get; set; }                                                                       
  public int[] Marks { get; private set; } 

  public StudentMarks(string surname, string name, string group, int amountOfMarks) 
  { 
    Surname = surname;                                                                                    
    Name = name; 
    Group = group; 
    Marks = new int[amountOfMarks]; 
  } 
} 

public static void ReadData(out StudentMarks[] Students, out int amount) 
{ 
  amount = 0; 
  Students = new StudentMarks[Max]; 
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P3\\P3.2\\StudentsMarks.csv")) 
  { 
    reader.ReadLine(); reader.ReadLine(); 
    string line = null; 
    while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) 
    { 
      string[] values = line.Split(','); 
      string surname = values[0]; 
      string name = values[1]; 
      string group = values[2]; 
      int i = 0; int yMax = 3 + amountOfMarks;int yMin = 4; 
      Students[amount]  = new StudentMarks(surname, name, group, amountOfMark); 
      while (amountOfMarks >= i) 
      { 
        if (yMin <= yMax) 
        { 
          Students[amount].Marks[i] = int.Parse(values[yMin]); 
          yMin++; 
        } 
        i++; 
      } 
      amount++; 
    } 
  } 
}
```